# In elastic search how to query place name using fuzzy search

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, fuzzy-search

I have inserted locations in elastic search, below is the sample elastic search stored locations:

```
[
  {
    "lat": 1,
    "lon": 1,
    "place": "asddda ddsd asdad vasanth hhjkhk sdsdd asddasd"
  },
  {
    "lat": 2,
    "lon": 2,
    "place": "asddda ddsd asdad vasanth1 hhjkhk sdsdd asddasd"
  },
  {
    "lat": 3,
    "lon": 3,
    "place": "asddda ddsd asdad vasanth2 hhjkhk sdsdd asddasd"
  },
  {
    "lat": 4,
    "lon": 4,
    "place": "asddda ddsd asdad test hhjkhk sdsdd asddasd"
  }
]
```

If i search for `vasanth` it is giving correct result, as it should give all 3 result. But if i search with charcter deletion `Vsanth` it is giving only one result but now also it should give 3 result. And also, if I insert a charcter then I also. Not working properly.

According to elastic search doc, it fuzzy query has the below features:

```
Changing a character (box → fox)
Removing a character (black → lack)
Inserting a character (sic → sick)
Transposing two adjacent characters (act → cat)
```

Below is the query I am using,

```
{
    "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
            "address": {
                "value": "Vsanth",
                "fuzziness":15,
                "transpositions":true,
                 "boost": 5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, how can I modify the query to use all four features of fuzzy query. I'm not getting what mistake I have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you have more edit distance to match `vasanth1 and vasanth2`.

[Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/common-options.html#fuzziness)

> The fuzziness parameter can be specified as:
>
> 0, 1, 2
>
> 0..2 = Must match exactly
>
> 3..5 = One edit allowed
>
> More than 5 = Two edits allowed

And you specified fuzziness as 15 so only two edits are allowed which is max in es.

So the problem here is that your query requires 3 edit distance which is not supported.

**Why 3:**

**Vsanth --> vsanth --> vasanth --> vasanth1**

1. Case changes -> capital V to lowercase v
2. Addition of a -> vasanth
3. one more Addition -> vasanth1

Hence you are getting the only `vasanth` matched docs.

And fuzzy queries are term queries, they will not be analysed. Adding lowercase filter to your `place` field's analyzer will not help here.

Comment: No. Fuzzy queries are term queries. You can achieve that using match query with fuzziness.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the "fuzzy" operator to have fuzzy searching in query_string:**

> This uses the Damerau-Levenshtein distance to find all terms with a
> maximum of two changes, where a change is the insertion, deletion or
> substitution of a single character, or transposition of two adjacent
> characters.

To get a detailed explanation, refer to this official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_fuzziness)

Adding a working example including Search query and Search result, taking the same sample index data as mentioned in the question

**Search Query:**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Vsanth~"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "foo",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1.0033107,
    "_source": {
      "lat": 1,
      "lon": 1,
      "place": "asddda ddsd asdad vasanth hhjkhk sdsdd asddasd"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "foo",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 0.8026485,
    "_source": {
      "lat": 2,
      "lon": 2,
      "place": "asddda ddsd asdad vasanth1 hhjkhk sdsdd asddasd"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "foo",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "3",
    "_score": 0.8026485,
    "_source": {
      "lat": 3,
      "lon": 3,
      "place": "asddda ddsd asdad vasanth2 hhjkhk sdsdd asddasd"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: @rahul did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you